# How to filter journalctl output by process name?

Tags: logging, journald, journalctl

When a process logs to systemd, its process name is recorded and displayed as identifier in the journalctl output.

```
$ systemd-cat echo "test"
$ journalctl -f
-- Logs begin at Sat 2018-02-24 12:13:24 CET. --
...
Jul 25 13:52:26 mycomputer echo[25098]: test
```

Filtering on that name, however, doesn't seem to work.

```
$ journalctl -f -t echo
-- Logs begin at Sat 2018-02-24 12:13:24 CET. --
$ journalctl -f -u echo
-- Logs begin at Sat 2018-02-24 12:13:24 CET. --
```

When I manually specify an identifier, the identifier is shown instead of the process name and filtering works.

```
$ systemd-cat -t myapp echo "test"
$ journalctl -f
-- Logs begin at Sat 2018-02-24 12:13:24 CET. --
Jul 25 13:56:08 mycomputer myapp[25213]: test
$ journalctl -f -t myapp
-- Logs begin at Sat 2018-02-24 12:13:24 CET. --
Jul 25 13:56:08 mycomputer myapp[25213]: test
```

How can I filter journalctl output on process name?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just figured this out. You can use any [systemd journal field](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.journal-fields.html#) as filter by specifying `<FIELD_NAME>=<VALUE>`.

The following fields are useful for this question:

> `_COMM=, _EXE=, _CMDLINE=`
>
> The name, the executable path, and the command line of the process the journal entry originates from.

So in order to filter on the command name, use `journalctl -f _COMM=<command-name>`

```
$ journalctl -f _COMM=echo
-- Logs begin at Sat 2018-02-24 12:13:24 CET. --
Jul 25 13:52:26 mycomputer echo[25098]: test
Jul 25 13:56:08 mycomputer myapp[25213]: test
```